# What is faster: ArrayList of int [] or int [][]

Tags: java, arrays

Which is more efficient, take less memory, faster to loop through and why?

case 1 :

```
ArrayList<int [9]>
```

case 2:

```
int [9][9]
```

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12254993/java-class-vs-array-memory-size

Comment: Well, one approach compiles...

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `ArrayList<int [9]>`?  The `Array` class only contains static methods, and isn't a templated type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Assuming you meant `ArrayList<>` rather than `Array<>`, since the latter is impossible].

By all technical measures, a native array will always be faster and smaller than an `ArrayList<>`, although the difference may in many cases be very minimal.  Internally an `ArrayList` uses a native array to store its elements, so it cannot possibly outperform that array.

However the `ArrayList<E>` has the advantage that it implements all of the `List<E>` interface as well as `Collection<E>` and `Iterable<E>`.  This can make your code far simpler by allowing  you to directly pass the object to any function that will accept parameters that `implement` those interfaces.

A further advantage of `ArrayList<E>` is that the array can transparently grow in size so it may be preferred if you do not know in advance how large the array has to be.  However that itself comes at a performance cost - if the new size is larger than the current capacity of the backing store array then a whole new array must be created, and then the original elements all copied into it - an `O(n)` operation.

Comment: downvoter - AFAIK, everything I've said here is absolutely technically correct.

Comment: I'm not downvoter, but OP also never pointed at Arraylist

Comment: @AkinOkegbile indeed, but then `Array<int []>` cannot possibly be correct.

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote, since this doesn't answer the question as asked at all.  Your assumption seems unwarranted, and it certainly isn't reflected by the question's title which has to do entirely with primitive arrays.  The appropriate action is to close as Unclear.

Comment: I've given the OP the benefit of the doubt that `Array<>` is simply a typo for `ArrayList<>`.  On that basis, everything I've said is correct, relevant to the question and certainly does _not_ merit a downvote.  Whether it's 1D or 2D makes no difference.

Comment: (except of course that `ArrayList<primitive>` is also impossible, that being the only point where 1D vs 2D matters in the question).

Comment: You can make a perfectly correct answer, but it doesn't matter if it doesn't answer the *question*.

Comment: @asteri well, the OP thinks I did answer the question.  Why don't you?

Comment: You got the check mark, fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant `ArrayList`?
if thats is what you meant: then an array (`int[][]`) is always faster than the list `ArrayList<Integer[]>`
Because `ArrayList` uses an array, and everytime you remove a value, it rewrites the whole array.

***Conclusion:*** unless you are going to consistently remove/add values NOT to the end of your "array", use a regular array (`int[][]`), but if you will, use `ArrayList<int[]>`

Comment: `ArrayList<int[]>` most certainly does compile; it's `ArrayList<int>` that doesn't.

Comment: It's a bit strange to say that ArrayList is slower than an array because remove is slow, since you can't remove anything from an array.

Comment: @JBNizet then, what IS the difference? If array is no faster than an arraylist, then why don't people ALWAYS use arraylists?

Comment: An ArrayList is backed by an array, as its name indicates. Calling get() or set() on an ArrayList is not significantly slower than reading or setting an element in an array. remove() needs moving elements, but there is no remove() on an array, so you can't compare. Why don't people always use ArrayLists? Well, to store objects, people almost always use them. Arrays are used for primitives mainly.

Comment: @JBNizet indeed `get()` and `set()` shouldn't be _significantly_ slower than a direct member access, but since they result in a function call they cannot possibly be _faster_.

Comment: @Alnitak we agree. Of course there is an overhead, but it's, almost always, insignificant. Choosing to use an array when you need the functionality of a List, just because you spare some cycles, is foolish in 99.999% of the cases.

Comment: @JBNizet I know, but still, Whats the point of having something that you won't use? These are just the essential rules of coding, Unless you NEED at least 1 feature of an ArrayList, Don't use it

Comment: @JBNizet that's fair, but nor do I adhere to the cargo cult that says you should always use an `ArrayList<foo>` instead of a `foo[]` regardless.  If, for example, I'm manipulating an image bitmap, then I'm certainly _not_ going to use an `ArrayList<>`.

Answer (score -2):

Array of `int[]` and `int[][]` are the same thing, called by different names. Considering that only one declaration is valid in java (the `int[][]`), whats the question?